# What is wrong with my algorithm for finding how many positive integers are divisible by a number d in range [x,y]?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I have been solving basic [counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting) problems from [Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics textbook (6th edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073229725).  These come from section 5-1 (the basics of counting), pages 344 - 347.

This question is not specifically about finding an answer to a problem or being given the correct equation, but whether my reasoning is sound.  Therefore I would find it hard to argue this is a duplicate of *seemingly* similar questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929373/how-many-integers-in-the-range-1-999-are-divisible-by-exactly-1-of-7-and-11) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588160/how-many-positive-integers-less-than-1000-are-divisible).

The problems I have been dealing with come of the form **How many positive integers in range [x,y] are divisible by d?**  All additional questions are based on the composition of the information learned in these, e.g. *how many positive integers in range [x,y] are divisible by d or e?*

To answer the simple question I wrote this "equation/algorithm," which takes as input an inclusive range of positive integers $[x,y]$ and a positive integer $d$, and returns $n$, the total number of positive integers in range $[x,y]$ which are divisible by $d$.

(1) $n = \left \lfloor{\frac{y}{d}}\right \rfloor - \left \lfloor{\frac{x}{d}}\right \rfloor$

The idea is that in order to count how many positive integers are divisible by $d$ from $[1,m]$, we simply calculate $\left \lfloor{\frac{m}{d}}\right \rfloor$, because every $dth$ positive integer must be divisible by $d$.  However, this does not work when given a range $[x,y]$ where $x \not= 1$ or when $x > 1$.  So we need to subtract the extra integers we counted, which is $\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{d}}\right \rfloor$, i.e. the number of positive integers divisible by $d$ from $[1,x]$.

For a sanity check, I also wrote a brute force algorithm that does a linear search over every positive integer in the range $[x,y]$ and counts it if $x \text{ mod } d == 0$.  It also can list out the integers it picked, in case I am feeling really paranoid.

With (1) I've been getting the correct answers except on this problem/input: *How many positive integers between 100 and 999 inclusive are odd?* My solution was to calculate how many are even, and subtract this from the total number of positive integers in range $[100,999]$.  To find the evens I simply use the algorithm in (1):

$\left \lfloor{\frac{999}{2}}\right \rfloor - \left \lfloor{\frac{100}{2}}\right \rfloor = 499 - 50 = 449$

But this answer is wrong, since there actually $450$ even numbers in range $[100,999]$ by the brute force algorithm.  (1) is somehow counting off by 1.  My question is, why is (1) failing for this input of $(2, [100,999])$ but so far it's worked on every other input?  What do I need to do to fix (1) so it produces the correct answer for this case?  Perhaps I'm actually over counting because $x$ should actually be $x - 1$?

(1') $n = \left \lfloor{\frac{y}{d}}\right \rfloor - \left \lfloor{\frac{x - 1}{d}}\right \rfloor$

(1') returns the correct answer for this specific input now, but I am not sure if it will break my other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After computing the number of positive multiples of $d$ less than or equal to $y,$ you correctly want to subtract the multiples that are not actually in the range $[x,y].$ Those are the multiples that are *less than* $x.$ When $x$ is divisible by $d,$ then $\left\lfloor \frac xd \right\rfloor$ counts all multiples of $d$ up to *and including* $x$ itself. So as you surmised, you want to subtract $\left\lfloor \frac {x-1}d \right\rfloor$ instead. This is true for any divisor, not just $d=2.$

Comment: You have identified and explained the problem nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have
$$
(k-1)d<x\leq kd<(k+1)d<\ldots<(k+n)d\leq y<(k+n+1)d.
$$
Then, you always have $\lfloor{\frac{y}{d}}\rfloor=k+n$ is $k+n$. On the other hand, if $x$ is divisible by $d$, then $\lfloor{\frac{x}{d}}\rfloor=k$, whereas if $x$ isn't divisible by $d$, then $\lfloor{\frac{x}{d}}\rfloor=k-1$. To rectify this, instead use $\lceil{\frac{x}{d}}\rceil$ which always returns $k$. Your solution is then
$$
n+1=(n+k)-k+1=\color{blue}{\left\lfloor{\frac{y}{d}}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil{\frac{x}{d}}\right\rceil+1}.
$$

---

p.s.
$$
(k-1)d<x\leq kd\implies(k-1)d\leq x-1<kd\implies\left\lfloor{\frac{x-1}{d}}\right\rfloor=k-1
$$
so that
$$
n+1=(n+k)-(k-1)=\color{red}{\left\lfloor{\frac{y}{d}}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor{\frac{x-1}{d}}\right\rfloor}.
$$
The formulas in blue and red produce the same answer.